# Jspirit timeunit set and speed in km/hr

Tags: jsprit

I am using Jsprit. I am calculating distance in km using the inbuilt greatcriclecost. I want to be sure that time unit for calculation should remain in hr. Moreover, speed in the great circlecost i set is 50Km/hr. It should behave accordingly.

after jsprit became graphhopper. most of the documentation was taken out from the internet. This is very disheartening to open source community. most of work done by Stefan Schröder has become tougher to use. I will be thankful to Stefan Schröder for his reply in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not Stefan. The projects were merged (which made a lot of sense) but Stefan is still leading the vehicle routing branch.

I'm not sure what documentation you refer to, but I'm not aware of any that has been removed. The old mailing list exists in a static state: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jsprit-mailing-list while new topics are actively answered in the new mailing list: https://discuss.graphhopper.com/c/jsprit . The Wiki appears to have kept the examples: https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/wiki and you can expand the list on the right hand side to see 80+ topics (this part I will agree was a little difficult to find).

"Moreover, speed in the great circlecost i set is 50Km/hr. It should behave accordingly." What makes you think it doesn't behave accordingly; is there a specific example of something going wrong? JSprit is unit agnostic but consistent throughout with whatever unit you work with. I could perhaps help with that if you can be more specific and there's an issue.

As for "disheartening"; it is perhaps a shame that certain (new) features are locked behind a subscription. However, the original code base before the merge is still open-source and added to in just the same manner as before. Recently, a job priority feature was added https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/issues/242 , for example, after Jsprit and graphhopper merged. It is an outsourced project in a lot of ways, but I really prefer that [the person clearly steering the ship with features](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/graphs/contributors) has the opportunity to take some profit and still maintains new open features.